# .sty file allowing a maximum number of characters/pages before compiling

Tags: packages

Is there a way for a `.sty` file to check for a maximum number of characters or pages in a given `section`, and stop compiling if this maximum is reached?

Would there also be a way to output a warning message in the console or in the `.pdf` once compiled?

Comment: Not really. The question isn't really very well specified, are you counting input characters of glyphs in the font output? how many characters are in `difficult` since depending on the font there might be no ligatures, and ff ligature or an ffi one. if ffi is three characters is an mdash entered as `---` also three, and if so what about an mdash entered as `\textemdash` ?. I'd just take an estimate of the average area of a character in your document and divide the area of the text block by that amount.

Comment: I mean input characters, such as in a "html textarea", to be precise.